How to fix " 'BmpImageFile' object has no attribute 'load_read' "?
I am a beginner and I am learning to code an image classifier. My goal is to get information about the file containing a graphic image in BMP 24 format. Display information about the image size, file size, and compare it with the size on the disk.
Code:
import os
from PIL import Image

# Get the file name from user input
file_name = input("file: ")

# Open the image file with PIL
with Image.open(file_name) as img:
    # Get image information
    width, height = img.size
    file_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)
    format_name = img.format

# Print image information
print(f"Image size: {width}x{height}")
print(f"File size: {file_size} bytes")
print(f"Format: {format_name}")

# Compare file size on disk with file size in memory
block_size = 512
disk_file_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)
memory_file_size = img.tobytes().nbytes

print("Comparing file size on disk with file size in memory:")
for i in range(0, disk_file_size, block_size):
    disk_block_size = min(block_size, disk_file_size - i)
    memory_block_size = min(block_size, memory_file_size - i)
    if disk_block_size != memory_block_size:
        print(f"Mismatch at offset {i}: disk={disk_block_size} bytes, memory={memory_block_size} bytes")
        break
else:
    print("File sizes on disk and in memory match.")

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 195, in load
    read = self.load_read
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'BmpImageFile' object has no attribute 'load_read'. Did you mean: 'load_end'?

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\OneDrive\Робочий стіл\program\LAb14\Lab\Lab14_1.py", line 27, in <module>
    memory_file_size = img.tobytes().nbytes
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 755, in tobytes
    self.load()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 199, in load
    read = self.fp.read
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

Any suggestion to fix it?
I expected to get information about a file containing a graphic image in BMP 24 format. Display information about the image size, file size, and compare it with the size on the disk.
But I got only: the image size, file size and format
